# mySQL Full Text search in Natural mode not returning partial match

Tags: php, mysql, sql, full-text-search

I am using mySQL Full text search in natural language mode and results are not returning as expected.

I have the following query where I am trying to return all results in my database that have 'Andrew' in any way in the suburb column - that is return all results where andrew is included ie %andrew%.

This is my query:

```
SELECT dud.suburb, 

MATCH (
dud.suburb
)
AGAINST (
'Andrew*'
) AS location
FROM dr_user AS du
LEFT JOIN dr_user_details AS dud ON ( dud.fk_userid = du.id ) 
LEFT JOIN dr_opening_hours AS dro ON ( dro.fk_userid = du.id ) 
LEFT JOIN dr_user_package AS dup ON ( du.id = dup.fk_userid
AND dup.status =1 ) 
LEFT JOIN dr_package AS dp ON ( dp.id = dup.package_type ) 
LEFT JOIN avail_time_child AS ap ON ( du.id = ap.fk_userid ) 
WHERE 
MATCH (
dud.suburb
)
AGAINST (
'Andrew*'
)
ORDER BY (
location
) desc
```

I Get No Results. 
Although I know that their is a suburb called 'St Andrews', when I update the query to search 'andrews' it comes up:

```
SELECT dud.suburb, 

MATCH (
dud.suburb
)
AGAINST (
'Andrews*'
) AS location
FROM dr_user AS du
LEFT JOIN dr_user_details AS dud ON ( dud.fk_userid = du.id ) 
LEFT JOIN dr_opening_hours AS dro ON ( dro.fk_userid = du.id ) 
LEFT JOIN dr_user_package AS dup ON ( du.id = dup.fk_userid
AND dup.status =1 ) 
LEFT JOIN dr_package AS dp ON ( dp.id = dup.package_type ) 
LEFT JOIN avail_time_child AS ap ON ( du.id = ap.fk_userid ) 
WHERE 
MATCH (
dud.suburb
)
AGAINST (
'Andrews*'
)
ORDER BY (
location
) desc
```

Results:

```
suburb  location
ST ANDREWS  9.374254227
ST ANDREWS  9.374254227
ST ANDREWS  9.374254227
ST ANDREWS  9.374254227
ST ANDREWS  9.374254227
ST ANDREWS  9.374254227
```

I understand that operators don't work in natural language, I have tried all combinations (*,%) with or without, makes no difference.

Can anyone please help with why these results don't show when I am querying for 'Andrew'?

Thanks,

Comment: Wildcard character works only in boolean mode, so try: `AGAINST (
'Andrew*'
 IN BOOLEAN MODE)`

Comment: Thanks Rims - I know that it works in boolean mode - but I want the score relevance. 

Is it possible for Natural mode to return partial results?

For example if I search for 'overflow', I would want the following results:

- stackoverflow
- overflows
- overflow

Thanks